# IndexError: list index out of range sys.argv[2]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm passing three parameters to another python file

```
subprocess.call(["python3","feedback.py",pro_id,pro_name,pro_price])
```

And in the feedback.py

```
pro_id=sys.argv[1]
pro_name=sys.argv[2]
pro_price=sys.argv[3]
```

there will be an error message: 
pro_name=sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

However it works successfully when I print the whole list of sys.argv like

```
counter = len(sys.argv)

for i in range(counter):
    print(sys.argv[i])
```

It will print the correct data in the list. How can I solve the error?

Comment: Why not *import* the functionality from `feedback.py`, and call it directly? If that's not possible, refactor until it is.

Comment: What does `print(sys.argv)` and `print(counter)` display in `feedback.py`?